# Google Custom Search tabs

Tags: search, google-custom-search

How can I create tabs to refine search results in Google Custom Search? An example is this: http://goo.gl/gftKp

Here, the results can be filtered as All Results, Blogs, Forum, Help, etc.. I am looking to do something like that. My website has different sections like articles, games, forum, gallery, etc.. How can I create tabs like these in the google custom search (free service) so users can filter the results and choose which section of the website they want to search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for a solution for the same context few months back and at last found a solution.

After adding [refinements](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631064?hl=en) in google cse control panel you'll see refinements as 'filter labels' for your search. But this feature, ie matching labels is too broad.

If your site has a specific path for each sections like,

- articles under mysite/articles/
- games under mysite/games/

then, you can map these paths to each filter or refinement you created before.

See the image below, I've added few refinements here as news,blog,media

[image: Here I've added a few refinements]

See the mapping below for each label/refinement

[image: mapping for each label]

and if you really want the refinement to appear like tabs..

[image: styling for refinements]

Happy 'custom search engin-ing' :)